# vs-code tomcat extension not refreshing static files (html, css, js..)

Tags: java, tomcat, gradle, visual-studio-code

I'm migrating from Eclipse to VS-Code for its lightweight. I'm work in a Java servelet program.

On Eclipse after any static file change it trigger a refreshing command to tomcat. Otherwise on VS-Code to get my changes be refreshed I have to stop tomcat server, build war file (using Gradle) and start tomcat server again.

It's OK to do that after Java classes changes, but for static resources it's very annoying.

I have the follow extensions installed for VSCode:
[Tomcat for Java (adashen.vscode-tomcat)](https://github.com/adashen/vscode-tomcat)

I think it's a simple configuration that I'm missing.
Thanks

Comment: do you want to change the local html or css,js files,then could refresh the webpage automatically？

Comment: Exactly! I'd like that it behave like running in Eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 1):

To use auto refresh in vs-code I had to give up using the Tomcat extension for Java (adashen.vscode-tomcat).

I use Gradle as build automation system so I tried **Gretty** to run my application. After setup it, I run the application with a simple command on the internal terminal of the vs-code (gradlew AppRun). It works perfectly.

The configuration is quite simple following links below:
- https://gretty-gradle-plugin.github.io/gretty-doc/Getting-started.htm

- https://guides.gradle.org/building-java-web-applications/#add_the_code_gretty_code_plugin_and_run_the_app

Comment: You can use the debug from VSCode IDE.